# Expandable List View Operator == cannot be applied

Tags: java, android

So today I created Expandable List View, everything went well without any error, excepts this in Adapter.java

I'm getting error: `Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'android:view.View', 'int'` in the if loop just below `String title` line.

Adapter.java

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String title = (String)this.getGroup(groupPosition);
    if(convertView == 0){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_531_layout, null);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading_item);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setText(title);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String title = (String)this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == 0){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_531_layout, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_item);
    textView.setText(title);

    return convertView;
}
```

So if anyone can correct my errors and tell me what I did wrong, I would appreciate it!

Comment: How is a view supposed to equal 0?

Comment: `if (convertView == null){`

Comment: I dont know, I just followed tutorial from Youtube, guy there didnt get any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View is an object and there is not logical(possible to compare this againt an int)
try checking if is a null reference or not.

```
 if (convertView == null){
...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Do you know why it wont expand in CardView but it will in empty activity?

Answer (score 1):

View here is the expandable list view item, you cann't directly compare it to any integer like you have done. 
If you want to check whether view is empty than check like this :

```
if (convertView == null){
//your code here
    }
```

Hope it helps !